# Read Bluetooth Data From Arduino to Android APP

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I have cloned and tried to Run this library.
https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary
And try if it will work, Unfortunately, I cant received any data from my Android APP.
I have tested My BLuetooth using [BT Simple Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wingood.bluetooth.btsimpleterminal&hl=en/BT%20SIMPLE%20TERMINAL),
And it can received my bluetooth data from my arduino..
But using Bluetooth SPP Library It cannot.

I Assumed that I supposed to read it here in this line with SPP Library Under
TerminalActivity. But nothing received.

```
 bt.setOnDataReceivedListener(new BluetoothSPP.OnDataReceivedListener() {
            public void onDataReceived(byte[] data, String message) {
                textRead.append(message + "\n");
            }
        });
```

And for my Arduino code,

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
const byte ROWS = 4; // Four rows
const byte COLS = 3; // Three columns
// Define the Keymap
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'7','8','9'},
  {'*','0','#'}
};
// Connect keypad ROW0, ROW1, ROW2 and ROW3 to these Arduino pins.
byte rowPins[ROWS] = { 22, 24, 26, 28 };
// Connect keypad COL0, COL1 and COL2 to these Arduino pins.
byte colPins[COLS] = { 30, 32, 34 }; 
int row=0;
int col=0;
// Create the Keypad
Keypad kpd = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );
// Create the LCD
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2);
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(10, 11);

void setup() {

  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("[1]Attendance");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("[2]Get Finger ID");

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Enter AT commands:");
  BTSerial.begin(38400);
}

void loop()
{
  char key = kpd.getKey();
  if(key){
    if(col>=16){
      col=0;
      row=1;
    }
    lcd.setCursor(col, row);
    lcd.print(key);
    col++;
    if(key=='*'){
        BTSerial.write("Test");
    }  
 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe U need read byte[] data argument ? Please debug, see if there are any data.

Comment: There isn't any data. 
Tried printing some texts but it wouldnt print under setOnDataReceivedListener.

Comment: But in BT Terminal i can received datas from bluetooth.